# Rails: Image Uploading Site. Home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, url-routing

```
class PhootosController < ApplicationController

before_action :logged_in_user

def index
  @phootos = Phooto.all.sample(1)
end

def new
end

def show
  @phooto = Phooto.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @phooto = current_user.phootos.build(phooto_params)
   if @phooto.save
     flash[:success] = "Photo created!"
     redirect_to uploads_url
   else
     redirect_to root_url
   end  
end

def favorite
  @phooto = Phooto.find params[:id]

  if request.put?
    current_user.favorites << @phooto
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully favorited #{@phooto.name}'
  elsif request.delete?
    current_user.favorites.delete(@phooto)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited #{@phooto.name}'
  else
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
  end    
end

def feed
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.all 
end  

def uploaded
  @phootos = current_user.phootos.all
end  

  private

 def phooto_params
   params.require(:phooto).permit(:picture)
 end
 end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><strong>Picture:</strong></p> 

<%= image_tag(@phooto.picture) %>

<%= link_to("< Previous", @phooto.previous) if @phooto.previous %>
<%= link_to("Next >", @phooto.next) if @phooto.next %>

<% if current_user %>
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_phooto_path(@phooto), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_phooto_path(@phooto), method: :delete %>

<% end %>

www.example.com/photos/1
```

Professional websites have the homepage www.example.com load with a photo already displayed. Then when you click next/previous, you are routed to `www.example.com/photos/#{photo_id}`

How do I get my website to do this? I also want it setup so that each day a different random photo is displayed in the homepage.

Comment: Looks like you already have it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a random photo on the homepage, you need the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :photos, only: [:index, :show]

#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
   def index
      random  = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'MySQL' ? "RAND()" : "RANDOM()"
      @phooto = Photo.order(random).first
   end

   def show
      @phooto = Photo.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Refs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536743/1143732  (adapter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577054/1143732 (random)

--

This will allow you to populate the `@phooto` variable in both the `index` and `show` actions;

```
#app/views/photos/index.html.erb
<%= render @phooto %>

#app/views/photos/show.html.erb
<%= render @phooto %>

#app/views/photos/_photo.html.erb
<p><strong>Picture:</strong></p> 

<%= image_tag(photo.picture) %>

<%= link_to("< Previous", photo.previous) if @phooto.previous %>
<%= link_to("Next >", photo.next) if @phooto.next %>

<% if current_user %>
   <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_phooto_path(phooto), method: :put %>
   <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_phooto_path(phooto), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

You'll be able to work out the rest.

---

In regards rendering a new random image each *day*, you'll have to store the "random" value each time the day changes.

This would be best done with a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), invoking a [rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake):

```
#lib/tasks/new_random.rb
namespace :random do
   task :generate => :environment do
      # save random for the day (maybe in a model or redis)
   end
end
```